# git how to remove all files which is not in directory and git add --all again

Tags: git

I just renamed a lot of files, e.g. `myfile.php` to `Myfile.php`. And realised that git ls-files shows old filenames. So I run `git add --all` and `git add`, `git commit` and `git push` etc. Then I realised that there are old and new files in my git repo and git ls-files.

Is there any way I can remove all git files and add again?

Comment: You should be running `git status` to see what changes are staged or unstaged.  You would have seen the rename operation listed there.  Are you sure you even have a problem?

Answer (score 0):

First run

```
git reset --soft
```

and then

```
git diff
```

to see the files that have changed.

After that add the files you want to commit and do git commit -m